# How to Refer to the Local path folder while using a web application(i.e hosted in server)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to read a text file from the local folder in my machine through a web application, but it always maps to server path. Is there any way to locate to my local machine instead of server path? I am using VB with ASP.NET.

```
strlocaldir = "C:\RJ\textfile.txt"
If File.Exists("strlocaldir") Then
    lblsysdir.Text &= "File exists :) " & strlocaldir
    '.......perform read operation
Else
    lblsysdir.Text &= "File does not exists :( " & strlocaldir
    'Exit out
End If
```

Comment: If file.exists needs no quotes, since you refer to a string variable.

Comment: Simple You can not read a file from the client. Only from server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any special file mapping that ASP.NET does, so you must mean that you're trying to access a file on the client machine without using `<input type=file>`. That's specifically *never* going to work, for security reasons: the only way you can do anything with existing files on the client is if they pass you the one to work with.

Comment: If I have a specific file on the Client machine and try to read it.. If that is possible, Please let me know How?

Comment: @Ruban.J it is not possible. Doesn't matter if you know the name or not: it's not allowed unless they specifically use the web browser's own dialogs (or drag-and-drop) for the job. Your code simply does not have the ability to pick up files.